# Table sorting implementation

Tags: angular

I use the [ngx-order-pipe](https://github.com/VadimDez/ngx-order-pipe) library to sort the table. The problem is that the up-down icons change, and the sorting itself does not work. It does not give any errors.

html:

```
<table class="centered highlight" *ngIf="filteredMasters.length !== 0" style="cursor: pointer">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th [class.active]="order === 'full_name'" (click)="setOrder('full_name')">Full Name <span [hidden]="reverse">▼</span><span [hidden]="!reverse">▲</span></th>
      <th [class.active]="order === 'date_work'" (click)="setOrder('date_work')">Date <span [hidden]="reverse">▼</span><span [hidden]="!reverse">▲</span></th>
      <th [class.active]="order === 'comment'" (click)="setOrder('comment')">Comment <span [hidden]="reverse">▼</span><span [hidden]="!reverse">▲</span></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
    <tr *ngFor="let master of filteredMasters | orderBy: order:reverse">
      <td>{{master.full_name}}</td>
      <td>{{master.date_work | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
      <td>{{master.comment}}</td>
      <td><a class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fa fa-edit" (click)="onSelectMaster(master)"></i></a></td>
      <td><a class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="fa fa-trash" (click)="deleteMaster(master)"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

ts:

```
  order: string = 'full_name'
  reverse = false

  setOrder(order) {
    this.order = order;
    this.reverse = !this.reverse;
  }
```

Comment: Have you updated _app.module.ts_ file?

Answer (score 0):

please add '**case-insensitive**' to your pipe. otherwise "**full_name**", "**comment**" has both uppercase and lowercase then you get two type of sorting one will get a bunch of records with "lowercase" and "uppercase" sorting.

1. will sort letters start will "lowercase" then it will show records which starts with "uppercase". -- In the case of DESC sorting
2. will sort letters start will "uppercase" then it will show records which starts with "lowercase". -- In the case of ASC sorting

The updated code is below.

```
<table class="centered highlight" *ngIf="filteredMasters.length !== 0" style="cursor: pointer">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th [class.active]="order === 'full_name'" (click)="setOrder('full_name')">Full Name <span [hidden]="reverse">▼</span><span [hidden]="!reverse">▲</span></th>
      <th [class.active]="order === 'date_work'" (click)="setOrder('date_work')">Date <span [hidden]="reverse">▼</span><span [hidden]="!reverse">▲</span></th>
      <th [class.active]="order === 'comment'" (click)="setOrder('comment')">Comment <span [hidden]="reverse">▼</span><span [hidden]="!reverse">▲</span></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
    <tr *ngFor="let master of filteredMasters | orderBy: order:reverse:'case-insensitive'">
      <td>{{master.full_name}}</td>
      <td>{{master.date_work | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</td>
      <td>{{master.comment}}</td>
      <td><a class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fa fa-edit" (click)="onSelectMaster(master)"></i></a></td>
      <td><a class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="fa fa-trash" (click)="deleteMaster(master)"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```